# What does "mostly-memory" mean?

Tags: raspberry-pi, arangodb

ArangoDB describus itself as a "mostly-memory" database, but I am not clear on the implications. The FAQ gives very little detail:

> ArangoDB is a “mostly memory” database, which means that it
>   appreciates RAM very much and is most performing when it is not forced
>   to swap data to the hard disk.

I am looking at running ArangoDB on a Raspberry Pi to serve two or three users. What are the implications of "mostly-memory" in such a context?

If it is unplugged for some reason will I lose data?

Comment: I would think that this section of the FAQ answers your questions: [What durability guarantees does ArangoDB offer?](https://www.arangodb.com/faq/#what-durability-guarantees-does-arangodb-offer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's mostly working in memory, but is also doing some work on disks.

More precisely, it works with memory-mapped files, so all the operations will eventually be saved to disk (or equivalent long-term storage), but because it doesn't wait (by default) for the persistence to disk to happen, it can benefit in performance from this.

The implications is that if you use this default you get better performance than you might expect otherwise, but if something brings it down before the save has happened (especially a sudden power failure) then you could lose data or have a corrupt database.

If you configure a collection for immediate synchronisation you protect against this, but the performance is affected.